# When was the number of the beast, 666, first identified as referring to Emperor Nero?

Tags: church-history, revelation, symbolism, origin, 666

The belief that the number of the beast in Revelation, 666, refers to Nero is a common theory now. When was this identification first suggested?

Comment: So you want specifically the number *666* to be associated with Nero, not merely the *antichrist* or *beast* to be associated with him?

Comment: I'm looking for 666 but I'm interested in those questions more generally. So if you know something I'd be interested. There's a certain sense where anyone who denies the Father and the Son could be considered "an antichrist" but 666 is probably referring to someone more specific.

Comment: There are several early fathers who associate the Beast of Rev. 13/17 with Nero.  But they don't specifically mention the number 666.  Some did attempt to decipher the meaning of the 666, but I haven't found any yet that explicitly draw a connection between it and Nero.

Comment: Who were the ones who associated him with the beast?

Comment: Victorinus of Pettau and Commodianus.

Comment: Are you looking for  a source earlier than Revelation? Because the book of Revelation seems to be the obvious answer.

Comment: The book of Revelation does not associate 666 with Nero. It tells the reader the number and lets the one with wisdom reckon its meaning.

Comment: That sounds like an association to me.

Comment: The book can't be its own exegesis.

Comment: You didn't ask for exegisis. You asked for the first instance of an association, which you just pointed out exists in Revelation.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask about the first Biblical commentary which made an explicit association between Nero and 666 as referenced in Revelation?

Comment: 666 exists in Revelation. Nothing about Nero.

Comment: Revelation is, by many accounts, about contemporary Rome, and its ruler. Thus it is "about" Nero. Something needn't mention it explicitly (and in this case, could not, for political reasons) to be about it.  This is Literature 101. You acknowledge this association in your very question (it seems to be part of the motivation for your question, in fact).

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me that the goal of the question is to discover the first extant, extrabiblical association between the number 666 and Nero.  But it wouldn't hurt to add the extra specification to the question.

Comment: @Flimzy No, its not an accepted assumption the Revelation is about contemporary Rome. Considering Nero died in 68 and the authorship of Revelation is in often dated in the 90's that would not hold true anyway.

Comment: @BenMordecai: I didn't say it was an accepted assumption. I said many accounts make the claim. And, as your question states, if that claim is true (which of course we can't settle here), then Revelation *does indeed* refer to 666 as associated with Nero. Put another way, your question leaves the possibility for the answer to be Revelation. IOW, someone could answer "Revelation said it first, according to X." If that's not the answer you want, it would be better to clarify.

Comment: The logic is like this: the belief that 666 in Revelation refers to Nero exists as a popular theory, therefore that theory has an origin. What is the earliest occasion of that theory?

Comment: I'm with Ben, because Rev  13:18 does not mention Nero: "for it is the number of a man; and his number is Six hundred threescore and six."  Someone, later than the first century decided that the man referred to here might have been Nero.

Comment: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a hermeneutics question but looking for a position held in church history

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time Nero is directly interpreted as 666 or 616 was in 1831.

> The riddle seems to have been forgotten almost as soon as it was written and not solved until 1831 (when it first was proposed), seemingly because the number was assumed to be Greek or Latin—and not a Hebraic one.

http://penelope.uchicago.edu/~grout/encyclopaedia_romana/gladiators/nero.html

About 270 Victorinus mentions Nero in his commentary on Revelation chapter 17, but when it comes to 666 he says the following.

> 18. “His number is the name of a man, and his number is Six hundred threescore and six.”] As they have it reckoned from the Greek characters, they thus find it among many to be τειταν, for τειταν has this number, which the Gentiles call Sol and Phœbus; and it is reckoned in Greek thus: τ three hundred, ε five, ι ten, τ three hundred, α one, ν fifty,—which taken together become six hundred and sixty-six. For as far as belongs to the Greek letters, they fill up this number and name; which name if you wish to turn into Latin, it is understood by the antiphrase DICLUX, which letters are reckoned in this manner: since D figures five hundred, I one, C a hundred, L fifty, V five, X ten,—which by the reckoning up of the letters makes similarly six hundred and sixty-six, that is, what in Greek gives τειταν, to wit, what in Latin is called DICLUX; by which name, expressed by antiphrases, we understand Antichrist, who, although he be cut off from the supernal light, and deprived thereof, yet transforms himself into an angel of light, daring to call himself light.2304 Moreover, we find in a certain Greek codex αντεμος, which letters being reckoned up, you will find to give the number as above: α one, ν fifty, τ three hundred, ε five, μ forty, ο seventy, ς two hundred,—which together makes six hundred and sixty-six, according to the Greeks. Moreover, there is another name in Gothic of him, which will be evident of itself, that is, γενσήρικος, which in the same way you will reckon in Greek letters: γ three, ε five, ν fifty, σ two hundred, η eight, ρ a hundred, ι ten, κ twenty, ο seventy, ς also two hundred, which, as has been said above, make six hundred and sixty-six.

Irenaeus (130-202) discusses 666 and 616 in chapters XXIX and XXX of Against the Heresies Book V, but he never mentions Nero. Here is an excerpt.

> 3. It is therefore more certain, and less hazardous, to await the fulfilment of the prophecy, than to be making surmises, and casting about for any names that may present themselves, inasmuch as many names can be found possessing the number mentioned; and the same question will, after all, remain unsolved. For if there are many names found possessing this number, it will be asked which among them shall the coming man bear. It is not through a want of names containing the number of that name that I say this, but on account of the fear of God, and zeal for the truth: for the name Evanthas (ΕΥΑΝΘΑΣ) contains the required number, but I make no allegation regarding it. Then also Lateinos (ΛΑΤΕΙΝΟΣ) has the number six hundred and sixty-six; and it is a very probable [solution], this being the name of the last kingdom [of the four seen by Daniel]. For the Latins are they who at present bear rule: I will not, however, make any boast over this [coincidence]. Teitan too, (ΤΕΙΤΑΝ, the first syllable being written with the two Greek vowels ε and ι, among all the names which are found among us, is rather worthy of credit. For it has in itself the predicted number, and is composed of six letters, each syllable containing three letters; and [the word itself] is ancient, and removed from ordinary use; for among our kings we find none bearing this name Titan, nor have any of the idols which are worshipped in public among the Greeks and barbarians this appellation. Among many persons, too, this name is accounted divine, so that even the sun is termed “Titan” by those who do now possess [the rule]. This word, too, contains a certain outward appearance of vengeance, and of one inflicting merited punishment because he (Antichrist) pretends that he vindicates the oppressed. And besides this, it is an ancient name, one worthy of credit, of royal dignity, and still further, a name belonging to a tyrant. Inasmuch, then, as this name “Titan” has so much to recommend it, there is a strong degree of probability, that from among the many [names suggested], we infer, that perchance he who is to come shall be called “Titan.” We will not, however, incur the risk of pronouncing positively as to the name of Antichrist; for if it were necessary that his name should be distinctly revealed in this present time, it would have been announced by him who beheld the apocalyptic vision. For that was seen no very long time since, but almost in our day, towards the end of Domitian’s reign.

Comment: This answer would have been better if you had pulled the quotes from the linked page that answered the question rather than post these long passages that don't.

Comment: That's precisely what I did with the first quote from the linked page. The last two quotes are from the Ante-Nicene fathers which many people will recognize and can be found at such places as ccel.org. The first quote answers the question very simply. The last  two show how early Christians understood the number, which is perhaps more important.

Answer (score 1):

This solution was reached independently by the German scholars Fritzsch, Benary,
Hitzig, and Reuss in the early part of the 19th century (Isbon T. Beckwith, *The Apocalypse of John*, pages 404-405):
https://books.google.com.tr/books?isbn=1579106099.  R. H. Charles in *International Critical Commentary*, p. 367 adds Holtzmann to the list and does not mention Fritzsch: https://archive.org/details/acriticalandexeg01charuoft.

Comment: This answer really requires some links or more definite references.

Comment: @Woofenden -- I have re-edited the answer, supplying the page numbers where the one sentence item is given in Beckwith and the Google Books link to the commentary.  Obviously, a seminary library containing those German commentators and a knowledge of German are necessary for those who wish to read what they had to say.